# Cannot cast InlineByteBuddyMockMaker on AndroidStudio 4.2.1

Tags: android-studio, unit-testing, mockito

I recently upgraded my Android Studio to 4.2.1 and I noticed that most of my tests (both Unit and AndroidTest) now fail with this error

```
Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in java.lang.CompoundEnumeration@1570cad0

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker to org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
```

My configuration in the build.gradle file is the following

```
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.28.2"
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8"

androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.28.2"
```

And if I launch the tests on my personal laptop (not the work one) where I am still on AS 4.1.2 then all runs smoothly.
It seems to be related to Robolectric but I have not been able to find the culprit, does anyone have any idea what changed and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

My project uses "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:x.x.x" before upgrade Android Studio to 4.2.1.

After I upgraded Android Studio to 4.2.1 I had the same problem.

My problem is solved by change

"com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:x.x.x"

to

"org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:x.x.x"
https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin